# VBA Worksheet change or calculate Event

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I've been through about 30-40 links about this type of problem but I haven't been able to find a solution for my specific problem.. Hope you can help me!

The setup is as follows;
In sheet1 there is a formula in column L (12) that uses a lookup-formula to look for a specific ID-number in sheet2. In sheet2 users paste a list of IDs everyday. If the lookup-formula on sheet1 **can't** find the ID in the list, it gives the value "Fixed".  I'd like to get a macro that automatically saves the entire row of the ID-number to sheet3 when it is changed to "Fixed" in sheet1.

The code I have so far in Sheet1 is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim keyCells As Range

Set keyCells = Columns(12)

On Error Resume Next
    Set keyCells = Application.Union(keyCells, keyCells.Precedents)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, keyCells) Is Nothing Then
 '   Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim a As Range

    For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(12))

        If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) And Target.Value = "Fixed" Then _
            a.EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=Sheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)      

    Next a
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that it only runs when I manually do a change on sheet1, not when a value is change to "Fixed" when I've done something on sheet2!

I have tried some versions with worksheet_calculate but then it runs all the time there is a change and not only in column L.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you want to run code when something is changed in `Sheet2`, then you need to handle the `Change` event on `Sheet2`. You may prefer to handle the `SheetChange` event in `ThisWorkbook` instead.

Comment: @Mat'sMug as I understood him he wants to trigger a macro when the value of a cell (**containing a formula**) changes by recalculation. But none of the `change` events triggers that, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Peh "In sheet2 users paste a list of IDs everyday" - handling the `Change` event on `Sheet2` would allow executing code when that pasting occurs. Unless I'm reading the OP backwards, the formulas are on `Sheet1`, in column L - where OP is listening for changes that happen when `Sheet2` is modified. If OP wants to pick up changes in `Sheet2`, they need to handle the `Change` event on `Sheet2`.

Comment: The last line of the code, make another cell equal the calculation cell, then use an if statement at the beginning, if that cell <> the target cell, then carry on with the calculation code.

Comment: @Mat's Mug you are correct! I can't believe I didn't test it! I will try this first thing tomorrow and hope for the best.